# Multi-File Packages need to unregister all classes from files

Tags: python, add-on

Blender (2.70a) is crashing with segmentation faults when I enable/disable/reenable my addon. I've inherited a project with a multi-file package design. I'm suspect that some classes are not unregistering since they aren't being called when the addon's unregister gets called.

I've reviewed this [cookbook](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Multi-File_packages). And in both examples there are no bpy.type.Operators except in the **__init__.py** file. But in my project some files have Operators and Panels and some don't.

Does anyone know if reregistering classes can cause a crash?
What's the point of calling ***bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)*** if it doesn't unregister. Here is my **__init__.py**

```
bl_info = {
   'name': 'MyTools',
   'author': 'Me',
   'version': (0, 3),
   'blender': (2, 69, 0),
   'location': 'bpy.ops.mytools',
   'description': 'MyTools',
   'warning': '',
   'wiki_url': '',
   'category': 'user'}

import os
import sys
import importlib


# import/reload all .py files dynamically
for file_name in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
  if file_name      == '__init__.py' or \
     file_name[-3:] != '.py'         or \
     file_name[0]   == '.'           or \
     file_name[0]   == '#':
       continue

  module_name = 'mytool.' + file_name[:-3]
  __import__(module_name, locals(), globals())

  module = sys.modules[module_name]
if 'bpy' in locals():
    print(module.__name__)
    importlib.reload(module)

if 'bpy' in locals():
  print('Reloaded Mytool AddOn')
else:
  print('Imported Mytool AddOn')

import bpy

def register():
  bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)


def unregister():
  bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  register()
```

And mock up of one of the other files. foo.py

```
from . import myUtils

import bpy

class myOp(bpy.types.Operator):
   bl_idname = "mytools.myop"
   bl_label = "my operator"
   def execute(self,context):
       self.report({'INFO'}, "awesome")
       return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(myOp)
```

Is this as simple as adding register and unregister methods to all of my other .py files.

Comment: The way you import the other files looks really odd. Why don't you use a more common way to import, that doesn't walk the directory? I'm not sure if this is causing the crashes however.

Comment: This is what I inherited. I'm trying not to have to refactor too much. The idea is to not have to edit the __init__.py every time you need to add file.

Comment: Did I mention that Blender is crashing like crazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are any custom PropertyGroup classes in the submodules, they have to be loaded in the correct order. You also need to "unregister" the submodules.

This is a pattern in the main file

```
def register():
    #register operators and propertyGroups explicitly
    bpy.utils.register_class(myPGClass1)
    #and/or run a helper function that finds all the classes and registers them

    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

    #add to the schema
    bpy.types.Scene.myTool = bpy.props.PointProperty(type=myPGClass1)


def unregister():

    #important: delete custom schema
    del bpy.types.Scene.myTool
    #unregister_classes, or use helper
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(myPGClass1)
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

The this should work find if everything is in the `__init__.py` file. But since this is not the case, then these are the issues I discovered.

1. register_module() just finds the `bpy.types.*` classes in the module and runs register_class which looks to be a python call into C. So this doesn't look in the other files. So one has to call `register_class` on anything defined there.
2. enabling and disabling scripts will find the `register` and `unregister` functions by duck-typing. But only the `__init__.py` file will be in the list that gets checked. So anything in `unregister()` will not get called. This is the `del types.myType` line.
3. even though registering and unregistering is not working. Reloading **will** import the submodules, thus causing erratic behavior and classes will be reregistering, and the schema will try to update from a dereferenced raw pointer.
4. disabling/enabling addons has more to do with marking modules with a flag than with loading and unloading modules. Loading happens on first load and reload(f8).

Comment: I noticed this flaw in scripts/addons/light_field_tools . If you enable/disable this addon enough times it crashes blender.